# Find invalid value in date field

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the text file with column `Date` and it also have some wrong data in date column like  `space` and characters `ABC`. I just want to maintain those records which have characters into the different file named as `Error_file.txt`.

Tried:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
from dateutil.parser import parse

datelist = ["11/Jan/2018 01:01:00", "" ,"01/01/17", "2016-01-02","KK"]

def is_date(string):
    try:
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    with open('error_file.txt', 'w') as error:
        for i in datelist:
            if is_date(str(datelist)) == True:
                #WRITE TO Output File
                print dparser.parse(i, fuzzy=True).date()
            else:
                #WRITE TO Error File
                print('Error line')
```

In the above given, record with `KK` should be maintained in `Error_file.txt`.

But getting following output:

```
Error line
Error line
Error line
Error line 
Error line
```

Comment: Why `if is_date(str(datelist)) == True`? Just `if is_date(str(datelist))` will do. Also why are you `str(datelist)`. Don't you want to parse each individual date? That would be `is_date(i)`. Also why import `dateutil.parser` as two different names?

Comment: Also all your output goes to stdout so your `output.txt` and `error_file.txt` don't do anything.

Comment: The answer here is `str(datelist)` does `is_date('["11/Jan/2018 01:01:00", "" ,"01/01/17", "2016-01-02","KK"]')` which fails for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass each element to the function.

**Ex:**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

datelist = ["11/Jan/2018 01:01:00", "" ,"01/01/17", "2016-01-02","KK"]

def is_date(string):
    try:
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
for i in datelist:
    print is_date(i)         #Update
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing individual dates to the function to check, but the whole list. Which makes the function return `False` every time.

You have to edit the code like this to solve the issue

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
from dateutil.parser import parse

datelist = ["11/Jan/2018 01:01:00", "" ,"01/01/17", "2016-01-02","KK"]

def is_date(string):
    try:
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    with open('error_file.txt', 'w') as error:
        for date in datelist:
            if is_date(date) == True:
                #WRITE TO Output File
                print(parse(date, fuzzy=True).date())
            else:
                #WRITE TO Error File
                print('Error line')


# Output

2018-01-11
Error line
2017-01-01
2016-01-02
Error line
```